# Ignore Attribute with AutoMap Reverse Attribute not working

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-12

I have a property that is Ignored with Ignore Attribute in a DTO with AutoMap Reverse.

When I try to get from DTO to entity, seem like the ignored attribute is being copied to destiny Entity, wouldn´t it be left on copy when source (dto) has the ignore map?

```
[AutoMap(typeof(User), ReverseMap = true)]
public class UserDto {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  
  [Ignore]
  public string Password { get; set; }
}

_mapper.Map(dto,user); <-- Password is being copy to user, should that happens?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, for that you need the attribute on the `User` entity.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu User entity will be generated using scaffolding script.

Comment: Then you should drop the attributes and use the fluent API.